# Problems with the SonarQube Directory Tangle Index

Tags: java, sonarqube

We're using the latest version (5) of SonarQube to analyze our project.  I have some questions about how it calculates the Directory Tangle Index (formerly Package Tangle Index) that I haven't been able to find answers to anywhere else.

1. Why does SonarQube need to access class files to calculate the tangle index?  What information does it need for that analysis that is not include in the java files?
2. When specifying the class-file location for above, why do we have to provide such a deep path?  I want to specify "project.sonar.java.binaries=/path/bin/" not "...=/path/bin/com/company/project/a/b/".  I would also be fine with "...=/path/bin/**/*.class" or some other wildcard.  To that end, do I need to specify a separate class-file location for each package in my project?  The issue we are having is that we are trying to generate the SonarQube config file via an automated process, and drilling down to find all the necessary paths is a problem--the information needed to do that is not available when the process runs.
3. Why, when I click on the link for "Directory Tangle Index", do I get a page stating "No DSM data available for the component"?  I read somewhere that for complex projects SonarQube can't provide the information on which directories are tangled.  Why not?  Or is the problem that we are only specifying one class-file path for each project, not listing all the separate subdirectories?

The tangle index sounds interesting, but if I can't drill down to which packages are showing tangles, then it won't be as much help for improving our code.

Comment: Can you please precise the sonar-java-plugin version you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is in fact three questions in that question :

1. This is mainly due to historical reasons. Semantic analysis in java analyzer is quite recent and previous to that it was really hard to be 100% sure of a type refered in a class from the sources (let's say that there was no tool to exploit the data). So the solution was to rely on an analysis of the bytecode.
2. `sonar.java.binaries` needs to point to the directories containing your `.class` files, but it is expected to be at the root package, because the look up for a class will be done assuming a package is a directory from one of the directories specified in the property. (so if `sonar.java.binaries` is defined to point to `path/bin`, for class `com.mycompany.A` we will look for `path/bin/com/mycompany/A.class` file).
3. This would require some more information to be able to help in details. (like the source of your statement).